# How do I properly substitute a variable for a fraction using Maple

Tags: substitution, maple

I'm wondering why the first substitution does not work, the second, however, does.

[image]

Comment: Is there a programing aspect to this question? If not, it might be off-topic. Please kindly read [this Help Center page](/help/on-topic) to learn what's on-topic here.

Comment: This is a question about programming in the Maple language, and it is altogether on-topic and appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g := q*N__1/N:

algsubs(N__1/N = X__1, g);

         q*X__1
```

(I gave a detailed explanation in an answer to your question [here](https://mapleprimes.com/questions/235565-Substitute-Properly).)